# Tealium Params Reporting

Tags: react-native, mobile, adobe, analytics, tealium

So I'm tasked with pulling out Tealium data for analytics. In particular they want me to pull janusID and invitationCode out of the data flow and send it to Tealium. This is a react-native app, btw. In the code I have found under profile_utils.ts this bit of code:

```
export const parseProfile = (resp: { readonly items: ApiProfile }): Profile => {
    const apiProfile: ApiProfile = resp.items

    const profile: Profile = {
        janusId: apiProfile.profile.identity_id,
        name: parseName(apiProfile),
        consent: [...apiProfile.consent.map(apiConsent => ({ ...apiConsent }))],
        invitationCode:
            apiProfile.profile.data["charli-pilot"].userData.props.inviteCode,
    }
    return profile
}
```

And under core.ts I have found under AppState I have found this bit of code:

```
const defaultAppState: AppState = {
    session: {
        accessToken: "",
        loggedIn: false,
        username: "",
    },
    profile: {
        janusId: "",
        name: "",
        consent: [],
        invitationCode: "",
    },
```

and this

```
tealiumParams: {
        account: "",
        profile: "",
        environment: "",
        endpoint: "",
        ios: "",
        android: ""
    },
```

I don't need to add janusID and invitationCode to the tealiumParams or do I need to? Since profile is already part of tealiumParams and profile contains the information I need specifically janusID and invitationCode I think it's all there. I just need to access AppState.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is enough context here to fully answer the question, but I'll have a go. Just to let you know, I work on the Tealium Device Integrations team, and we maintain the React Native plugin (https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Mobile-Libraries/Tealium-for-React-Native/ta-p/22449). That `tealiumParams` object isn't known to us, so it must be an internal thing in your app, perhaps representing the Tealium data layer and configuration data. I'm assuming you are the app developer, and have been asked to send some data to Tealium using the Tealium React Native Plugin. Looking at your `tealiumParams` object, I believe the `profile` property represents your Tealium profile, which is a static string that tells the Tealium API which configuration to fetch (each Tealium customer has a single account and one or more "profiles" with separate configurations). The `profile` property in your defaultAppState object, on the other hand, seems to represent an app user's unique profile.

I believe you probably do want to add janusId and invitationCode to the Tealium data layer, since this would be useful information to [Tealium iQ](https://tealium.com/gb/products/tealium-iq-tag-management-system/) or [Tealium AudienceStream](https://tealium.com/gb/products/audiencestream/). Janus appears to be an identity resolution product, and I'm guessing that invitationCode is a code that your app user may have used as a promo code when they downloaded the app; again, this could be useful to know within the Tealium ecosystem. In general, it is better to make more information available to Tealium early on in your app development cycle, to minimise the need for app releases purely for tracking purposes. If you are unsure about what data is required, I'd suggest you work with the team who asked you to implement Tealium in the first place, and ask them what data they would like to be tracked. Our friendly support team is available also, should you have any questions that aren't answered by our documentation.

A better place to ask this question in future would be the [Tealium Learning Community](https://community.tealiumiq.com), where you can get Tealium-specific advice and guidance from other Tealium customers and experts. I hope this is useful information.